# GIT - After pushing change to dev branch, they got removed from local as well as remote branch

Tags: git, git-push

I have pushed my changes to dev branch before 2 days and team members are not getting those changes after pulling it. And the main problem is they are not even in my local copy. What should I do or what should be the possible reasons for happening this?

Need help.

Comment: Are you on a different branch? Try looking through the output of `git log --all` and see if you can find it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember your commit message, you can search for said commit in all your history, including the [local reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) (which includes deleted or non-referenced past commits) with [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

```
git log  --grep="a word" -- --all
git log -g --grep="a word"
```

If you remember of a word you have introduced in that commit (like the name of a new function), you can search for it with a [`git log` pickaxe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt):

```
git log  -S"a word" -- --all
git log -g -S"a word"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the following content somewhere in ~/.bashrc:

```
__hg_ps1() {
    local INFO
    INFO=$(hg branch 2> /dev/null)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "[$INFO $(hg status | cut -b 1 | uniq | sort | tr -d '\n')]"
    fi
}

export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;33m\]$(__git_ps1)$(__hg_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$"
```

This will give your terminal window (or cygwin terminal) additional information about the status of your git and/or mercurial repository. It will help you see e.g. what branch you're currently on.

If you're on the dev branch and you've pushed to the dev branch you should see your files locally. However, if you are locally on another branch, or if you pushed e.g. to your own version of the dev branch instead of a shared dev branch, your files may have been pushed to a place only you are using, and since you're on another branch locally the files will no longer be visible locally since they only exist on another branch than the one you're one.

So, verify that you're on the right branch, verify that you pushed to the right repository containing the right branch (yes, the right repository, you could have e.g. Simon/dev-branch and Team/dev-branch, if you pushed to Simon/dev-branch and the rest are pulling from Team/dev-branch they wouldn't see your pushed content because you're pushing to your own version of the branch).